# Cypress-IO: Modal page opens but will not load

Tags: javascript, cypress

In our E2E test using Cypress, we perform a room booking in an hotel. After all of the selections are made and billing details entered, a final button click takes the user to a modal payment page.

When running the test, Cypress triggers the modal load BUT the window nevel populates - just a fast moving thermometer. See screenshot.

[image: Payment page]

In a normal run this thermometer would be replaced with a credit Card payment routine.

It's fairly clear from the Console that the modal is a new URL but it's OUR URL not an external one.
[image: Console]

It's the same behaviour in Chrome and Electron.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Is it iframe? Have you try to do locally and it works

Comment: It may be a timing issue, which means the elements are in the DOM and cypress is already taken action even before they are visible on your Browser.
Add a cy.wait command and see if the page renders after a while. If not, inspect your browser and check what is going on.

Comment: @N..Yes this is an iFrame. When running locally - that is, not in a test, it works fine. Also OK when using Selenium/Protractor.

Comment: @Cleriston Thanks. I tried a `cy.wait` but no difference. When observing the behaviour in the console for a Cypress run and a manual run, the output is identical.

Comment: Cy.wait is not the solution. It is a workaround to find it. You need to understand what is going on with your DOM.